# How to mirror the following object?

Tags: modeling, mirror

I'm trying to create a wheelbase (see image below) for an office chair and I'm wondering if there is a way to mirror one part of the leg to the rest of the wheelbase? That way, when I model that one part, the rest will be modeled automatically.

[image]

I started the modeling process with a cylinder (5 verticies) and extruded each side to create each leg. However, as I started adding details, I realize I have to do it for each leg. Is there a better way to do this?  I imagine there is some way where I can "mirror" the mesh of one leg to the others automatically.

[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with an *Array* modifier and choose an empty as *Object Offset*.

Create a circle, extrude up, only keep 1/4 (or 1/5 if you need 5 legs), create an empty at the same location as the circle origin:

[image]

Give your object an *Array* modifier with the empty as *Object Offset*:

[image]

Rotate the empty on Z (90° if you have 4 legs, 72° if you have 5 legs):

[image]

Comment: Also select the Merge check box if the legs have been modelled to exactly match the next array instance and it will automatically merge the overlapping vertices.

Comment: Yes you're right, I've edited

Comment: Thanks both. I tried this with a cylinder and it works until I applied the subdiv modifier. The center (arrays) don't become round. You can see this in my post (just added the result). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Update, I just deleted the face that has the problem and now everything is fine